# How to find the angle of a right triangle which is situated in between to bisector segments?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

The problem is as follows:

> Using the figure from below find $x$.

[image: Sketch of the problem]

The alternatives given in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&40^{\circ}\\
2.&20^{\circ}\\
3.&10^{\circ}\\
4.&36^{\circ}\\
5.&18^{\circ}\\
\end{array}$

I've attempted to solve this problem but I came stuck with how to relate the angle in the right triangle, as it is suspiciously half of what it is in the intersection between two bisector segments.

But I don't know what to do from there. Can someone help me here?. **Please include a drawing in your answer** as trying to understand solely from reading algebraic expressions is difficult for me. The thing is I think this might require a construction or something like that. Can this be solved relying only in euclidean geometry?. Please explain this in a step-by-step approach as I'm not sure what sort of identity can be used to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In quadrilateral $ABCD, $

$360^0 = 180^0 - 2 \alpha + 180^0 - 2 \theta + 90^0 + x + 90^0$

So, $2 \theta + 2 \alpha -x = 180^0$ ...(i)

In $ \triangle ADE$,

$\theta + \alpha + 2x = 180^0$ ...(ii)

From $(ii) \times 2 - (i), 5x = 180^0$,

So $x = 36^0$